# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method buildUponParameters()

Tags: flutter, dart

I m trying a show a video player with better_player. It s a mpd file with your own clearKeys.I dont know whats happend here.
I m using Flutter stable channel and firebase auth , firebase core, dio, animate_do, go_router, better_player and other things inproyect
Please Help
Here is the debug console

```dart
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:49305/wlUjGxgYhgo=/ws
I/FirebaseApp(11398): Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
D/EGL_emulation(11398): app_time_stats: avg=66.74ms min=5.48ms max=655.69ms count=22
D/EGL_emulation(11398): app_time_stats: avg=34.31ms min=4.66ms max=229.72ms count=28
D/EGL_emulation(11398): app_time_stats: avg=31.12ms min=5.10ms max=64.11ms count=31
D/EGL_emulation(11398): app_time_stats: avg=33.35ms min=5.87ms max=441.44ms count=26
D/EGL_emulation(11398): app_time_stats: avg=388.59ms min=11.69ms max=2400.71ms count=7
D/EGL_emulation(11398): app_time_stats: avg=212.27ms min=11.71ms max=2662.68ms count=14
D/EGL_emulation(11398): app_time_stats: avg=22.48ms min=3.64ms max=350.06ms count=36
D/EGL_emulation(11398): app_time_stats: avg=90.05ms min=3.82ms max=858.74ms count=10
I/ExoPlayerImpl(11398): Init 77e19c [ExoPlayerLib/2.18.7] [emulator64_x86_64_arm64, sdk_gphone64_x86_64, Google, 31]
W/oflores.nadeli(11398): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioTrack;->getLatency()I (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
D/EGL_emulation(11398): app_time_stats: avg=1609.35ms min=2.16ms max=27194.05ms count=17
I/DrmHal  (11398): found instance=clearkey version=android.hardware.drm@1.4::IDrmFactory
I/DrmHal  (11398): found instance=default version=android.hardware.drm@1.0::IDrmFactory
I/DrmHal  (11398): found instance=widevine version=android.hardware.drm@1.4::IDrmFactory
D/EGL_emulation(11398): app_time_stats: avg=19.49ms min=5.84ms max=222.59ms count=41
D/CryptoHal(11398): found drm@1.0 ICryptoFactory clearkey
D/CryptoHal(11398): found drm@1.0 ICryptoFactory default
D/CryptoHal(11398): found drm@1.0 ICryptoFactory widevine
D/CryptoHal(11398): found drm@1.1 ICryptoFactory clearkey
D/CryptoHal(11398): found drm@1.1 ICryptoFactory widevine
E/CryptoHal(11398): Failed to make crypto plugin
I/DMCodecAdapterFactory(11398): Creating an asynchronous MediaCodec adapter for track type video
D/CCodec  (11398): allocate(c2.goldfish.h264.decoder)
I/Codec2Client(11398): Available Codec2 services: "default" "software"
I/CCodec  (11398): setting up 'default' as default (vendor) store
I/CCodec  (11398): Created component [c2.goldfish.h264.decoder]
D/CCodecConfig(11398): read media type: video/avc
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11398): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.max-count.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11398): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.subscribed-indices.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11398): extent() != 1 for single value type: input.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11398): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11398): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11398): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.pool-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11398): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.pool-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11398): ignored struct field coded.color-format.locations
D/CCodecConfig(11398): ignoring local param raw.size (0xd2001800) as it is already supported
D/CCodecConfig(11398): ignoring local param default.color (0x5200180b) as it is already supported
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11398): ignored struct field raw.hdr-static-info.mastering
I/CCodecConfig(11398): query failed after returning 12 values (BAD_INDEX)
D/CCodecConfig(11398): c2 config diff is Dict {
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 coded.pl.level = 20496
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 coded.pl.profile = 20481
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 coded.vui.color.matrix = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 coded.vui.color.primaries = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 coded.vui.color.range = 2
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 coded.vui.color.transfer = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 default.color.matrix = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 default.color.primaries = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 default.color.range = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 default.color.transfer = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 input.buffers.max-size.value = 2097152
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 input.delay.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   string input.media-type.value = "video/avc"
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 output.delay.value = 8
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   string output.media-type.value = "video/raw"
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.color.matrix = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.color.primaries = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.color.range = 2
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.color.transfer = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.max-size.height = 240
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.max-size.width = 320
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.pixel-format.value = 35
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::i32 raw.rotation.flip = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::i32 raw.rotation.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.sar.height = 1
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.sar.width = 1
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.size.height = 240
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.size.width = 320
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2:
W/ColorUtils(11398): expected specified color aspects (2:0:0:0)
I/MediaCodec(11398): MediaCodec will operate in async mode
D/SurfaceUtils(11398): connecting to surface 0x7e476d28a530, reason connectToSurface
I/MediaCodec(11398): [c2.goldfish.h264.decoder] setting surface generation to 11671553
D/SurfaceUtils(11398): disconnecting from surface 0x7e476d28a530, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/SurfaceUtils(11398): connecting to surface 0x7e476d28a530, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/CCodec  (11398): [c2.goldfish.h264.decoder] buffers are bound to CCodec for this session
D/CCodecConfig(11398): no c2 equivalents for csd-1
D/CCodecConfig(11398): no c2 equivalents for log-session-id
D/CCodecConfig(11398): no c2 equivalents for native-window
D/CCodecConfig(11398): no c2 equivalents for flags
D/CCodecConfig(11398): config failed => CORRUPTED
D/CCodecConfig(11398): c2 config diff is   c2::u32 raw.max-size.height = 1080
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.max-size.width = 1920
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.size.height = 576
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.size.width = 1024
W/Codec2Client(11398): query -- param skipped: index = 1107298332.
D/CCodec  (11398): client requested max input size 1566720, which is smaller than what component recommended (2097152); overriding with component recommendation.
W/CCodec  (11398): This behavior is subject to change. It is recommended that app developers double check whether the requested max input size is in reasonable range.
D/CCodec  (11398): setup formats input: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t height = 576
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t level = 65536
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t max-input-size = 2097152
D/CCodec  (11398):   string mime = "video/avc"
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t profile = 65536
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t width = 1024
D/CCodec  (11398):   Rect crop(0, 0, 1023, 575)
D/CCodec  (11398): }
D/CCodec  (11398): setup formats output: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t android._color-format = 2135033992
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t android._video-scaling = 1
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t rotation-degrees = 0
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t color-standard = 1
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t color-range = 2
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t color-transfer = 3
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t sar-height = 1
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t sar-width = 1
D/CCodec  (11398):   Rect crop(0, 0, 1023, 575)
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t width = 1024
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t height = 576
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t max-height = 1080
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t max-width = 1920
D/CCodec  (11398):   string mime = "video/raw"
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t android._dataspace = 260
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t color-format = 2130708361
D/CCodec  (11398): }
I/CCodecConfig(11398): query failed after returning 12 values (BAD_INDEX)
D/MediaCodec(11398): keep callback message for reclaim
W/Codec2Client(11398): query -- param skipped: index = 1342179345.
W/Codec2Client(11398): query -- param skipped: index = 2415921170.
W/Codec2Client(11398): query -- param skipped: index = 1610614798.
W/Codec2Client(11398): query -- param skipped: index = 2684356609.
D/C2Store (11398): Using DMABUF Heaps
D/CCodecBufferChannel(11398): [c2.goldfish.h264.decoder#22] Created input block pool with allocatorID 16 => poolID 17 - OK (0)
I/DMABUFHEAPS(11398): Using DMA-BUF heap named: system
D/CCodecBufferChannel(11398): [c2.goldfish.h264.decoder#22] Query output surface allocator returned 0 params => BAD_INDEX (6)
I/CCodecBufferChannel(11398): [c2.goldfish.h264.decoder#22] Created output block pool with allocatorID 18 => poolID 21 - OK
D/CCodecBufferChannel(11398): [c2.goldfish.h264.decoder#22] Configured output block pool ids 21 => OK
D/Codec2-OutputBufferQueue(11398): remote graphic buffer migration 0/0
D/Codec2Client(11398): setOutputSurface -- failed to set consumer usage (6/BAD_INDEX)
D/Codec2Client(11398): setOutputSurface -- generation=11671553 consumer usage=0x900
D/Codec2Client(11398): Surface configure completed
I/MediaDrm(11398): Drm event (4,0)
D/CryptoHal(11398): found drm@1.0 ICryptoFactory clearkey
D/CCodecConfig(11398): c2 config diff is   c2::u32 raw.color.matrix = 1
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.color.primaries = 1
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.color.transfer = 3
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.crop.height = 576
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.crop.left = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.crop.top = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.crop.width = 1024
D/CryptoHal(11398): found drm@1.0 ICryptoFactory default
D/CryptoHal(11398): found drm@1.0 ICryptoFactory widevine
D/CryptoHal(11398): found drm@1.1 ICryptoFactory clearkey
D/CryptoHal(11398): found drm@1.1 ICryptoFactory widevine
E/CryptoHal(11398): Failed to make crypto plugin
I/DMCodecAdapterFactory(11398): Creating an asynchronous MediaCodec adapter for track type audio
D/CCodec  (11398): allocate(c2.android.aac.decoder)
I/CCodec  (11398): setting up 'default' as default (vendor) store
I/CCodec  (11398): Created component [c2.android.aac.decoder]
D/CCodecConfig(11398): read media type: audio/mp4a-latm
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11398): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.max-count.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11398): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.subscribed-indices.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11398): extent() != 1 for single value type: input.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11398): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11398): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11398): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.pool-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(11398): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.pool-ids.values
I/CCodecConfig(11398): query failed after returning 19 values (BAD_INDEX)
D/CCodecConfig(11398): c2 config diff is Dict {
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 coded.aac-packaging.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 coded.bitrate.value = 64000
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 coded.pl.level = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 coded.pl.profile = 8192
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::i32 coding.drc.album-mode.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::float coding.drc.attenuation-factor.value = 1
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::float coding.drc.boost-factor.value = 1
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::i32 coding.drc.compression-mode.value = 3
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::i32 coding.drc.effect-type.value = 3
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::float coding.drc.encoded-level.value = 0.25
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::float coding.drc.reference-level.value = -16
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 input.buffers.max-size.value = 8192
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 input.delay.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   string input.media-type.value = "audio/mp4a-latm"
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 output.delay.value = 2
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::float output.drc.output-loudness.value = 0.25
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   string output.media-type.value = "audio/raw"
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.channel-count.value = 1
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.max-channel-count.value = 8
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.sample-rate.value = 44100
D/CCodecConfig(11398): }
I/MediaCodec(11398): MediaCodec will operate in async mode
D/CCodec  (11398): [c2.android.aac.decoder] buffers are bound to CCodec for this session
D/CCodecConfig(11398): no c2 equivalents for log-session-id
D/CCodecConfig(11398): no c2 equivalents for flags
D/CCodecConfig(11398): c2 config diff is   c2::u32 raw.channel-count.value = 2
D/CCodecConfig(11398):   c2::u32 raw.sample-rate.value = 48000
W/Codec2Client(11398): query -- param skipped: index = 1107298332.
D/CCodec  (11398): setup formats input: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t aac-drc-album-mode = 0
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t aac-drc-boost-level = 127
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t aac-drc-cut-level = 127
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t aac-drc-effect-type = 3
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t aac-encoded-target-level = -1
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t aac-max-output-channel_count = 8
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t aac-target-ref-level = 64
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t bitrate = 64000
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t channel-count = 2
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t level = 0
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t max-input-size = 8192
D/CCodec  (11398):   string mime = "audio/mp4a-latm"
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t profile = 2
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t sample-rate = 48000
D/CCodec  (11398): }
D/CCodec  (11398): setup formats output: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t aac-drc-album-mode = 0
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t aac-drc-boost-level = 127
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t aac-drc-cut-level = 127
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t aac-drc-effect-type = 3
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t aac-drc-output-loudness = -1
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t aac-encoded-target-level = -1
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t aac-max-output-channel_count = 8
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t aac-target-ref-level = 64
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t channel-count = 2
D/CCodec  (11398):   string mime = "audio/raw"
D/CCodec  (11398):   int32_t sample-rate = 48000
D/CCodec  (11398): }
I/CCodecConfig(11398): query failed after returning 19 values (BAD_INDEX)
D/MediaCodec(11398): keep callback message for reclaim
W/Codec2Client(11398): query -- param skipped: index = 1342179345.
W/Codec2Client(11398): query -- param skipped: index = 2415921170.
W/Codec2Client(11398): query -- param skipped: index = 1610614798.
D/CCodecBufferChannel(11398): [c2.android.aac.decoder#78] Created input block pool with allocatorID 16 => poolID 18 - OK (0)
I/CCodecBufferChannel(11398): [c2.android.aac.decoder#78] Created output block pool with allocatorID 16 => poolID 30 - OK
D/CCodecBufferChannel(11398): [c2.android.aac.decoder#78] Configured output block pool ids 30 => OK
W/MediaCodec(11398): mapFormat: no mediaType information
D/CCodecBuffers(11398): [c2.android.aac.decoder#78:EncryptedInput.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 1)
D/CCodecBuffers(11398): [c2.android.aac.decoder#78:EncryptedInput.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 2)
D/CCodecBuffers(11398): [c2.android.aac.decoder#78:EncryptedInput.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 3)
D/EGL_emulation(11398): app_time_stats: avg=21.80ms min=4.86ms max=80.32ms count=40
E/AndroidRuntime(11398): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11398): Process: com.gustavoflores.nadelis, PID: 11398
E/AndroidRuntime(11398): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method buildUponParameters()Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/trackselection/DefaultTrackSelector$ParametersBuilder; in class Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/trackselection/DefaultTrackSelector; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector' appears in /data/app/~~6tzwid5tXo0mo5Y8D0Ikbw==/com.gustavoflores.nadelis-bRDpQlhnqDx1j6TBEf8MOw==/base.apk)
E/AndroidRuntime(11398):    at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayer.setTrackParameters(BetterPlayer.kt:547)
E/AndroidRuntime(11398):    at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.onMethodCall(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:185)
E/AndroidRuntime(11398):    at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.onMethodCall(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:138)
E/AndroidRuntime(11398):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)
E/AndroidRuntime(11398):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/AndroidRuntime(11398):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/AndroidRuntime(11398):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/AndroidRuntime(11398):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/AndroidRuntime(11398):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(11398):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(11398):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(11398):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
E/AndroidRuntime(11398):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11398):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime(11398):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
I/oflores.nadeli(11398): Background concurrent copying GC freed 66846(4066KB) AllocSpace objects, 23(1008KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 6672KB/13MB, paused 720us,337us total 210.274ms
I/Process (11398): Sending signal. PID: 11398 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.

Exited.
```

Heres th flutter doctor

```dart
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.1, on Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.22631.3085], locale es-AR)
    • Flutter version 3.16.1 on channel stable at C:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7f20e5d18c (9 weeks ago), 2023-11-27 09:47:30 -0800
    • Engine revision 6e2ea58a5c
    • Dart version 3.2.5
    • DevTools version 2.28.5

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\gutaf\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.5.33516.290
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)

[√] VS Code (version 1.85.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\gutaf\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.80.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 12 (API 31) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.22631.3085]
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 121.0.6167.85
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 120.0.2210.144

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

and here the WidgetScreen

```dart
import 'package:better_player/better_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LiveChannelTvScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const name = 'live-tv';
  const LiveChannelTvScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LiveChannelTvScreen> createState() => _LiveChannelTvScreenState();
}

class _LiveChannelTvScreenState extends State<LiveChannelTvScreen> {
  late BetterPlayerController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BetterPlayerDataSource betterPlayerDataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
        BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network,
        videoFormat: BetterPlayerVideoFormat.dash,
        liveStream: true,
        bufferingConfiguration: const BetterPlayerBufferingConfiguration(),
        drmConfiguration: BetterPlayerDrmConfiguration(
          drmType: BetterPlayerDrmType.clearKey,
          clearKey: BetterPlayerClearKeyUtils.generateKey(
            {
              "MyKeyId":
                  "MyKeyhex"
            },
          ),
        ),
        "https://edge-vod02-sl.myurl.mpd");
    controller = BetterPlayerController(
        const BetterPlayerConfiguration(fit: BoxFit.cover),
        betterPlayerDataSource: betterPlayerDataSource);
    setState(() {
      controller;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          child: BetterPlayer(
            controller: controller,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Everything was running fine and suddenly this error happened.